# How to open the PDF file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

How to open the PDF file using AJAX
I tried this

```
$.ajax({

          type : 'GET',
          url : ApplicationParameters.getWebRoot() + 'E_Books/pdf/previews/' + jsonRecord[0].previewUrl,
          data : strJsonParam,
          dataType : 'text',
          contentType : 'application/pdf',

          success: function(data){
          var opn = open("/E_Books/pdf/previews/"+jsonRecord[0].previewUrl);
          displayBook(opn);
          ebookStore.add(opn);
          ebookStore.sync();
    }
    ...
```

it open pdf file but I want open that in same window.it open in another window.
help please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
            type : 'GET',
            url : ApplicationParameters.getWebRoot() + 'E_Books/pdf/previews/' + jsonRecord[0].previewUrl,
            data : strJsonParam,
            dataType : 'text',
            contentType : 'application/pdf',

            success: function(data){
            var opn = open("/E_Books/pdf/previews/"+jsonRecord[0].previewUrl, "_self");
                    displayBook(opn);
                    ebookStore.add(opn);
                    ebookStore.sync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ajax for this. In your code above it is the line
 var `opn = open("/E_Books/pdf/previews/"+jsonRecord[0].previewUrl);` that opens your pdf in a new window. Not the ajax call.

Just set `document.location = "/E_Books/pdf/previews/"+jsonRecord[0].previewUrl` to replace the page that is displayed in the browser with your pdf.

Comment: It might be that you need the getWebRoot call as well: `document.location = ApplicationParameters.getWebRoot() + 'E_Books/pdf/previews/' + jsonRecord[0].previewUrl`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this..

```
window.location.href="/E_Books/pdf/previews/"+jsonRecord[0].previewUrl";
```

or

```
window.location="/E_Books/pdf/previews/"+jsonRecord[0].previewUrl";
```